# How to insert elements from one list to another generating all possible combinations

Tags: python, list, insert

Hello guys I need some help with lists in python. Suppose I have two lists.

```
a = [3,1,5]
b = [2,4]
```

What I want is to insert the elements of the list b consecutively (without changing the order of a) generating new lists. For example.

```
ans = [[2,4,3,1,5],[2,3,4,1,5],[2,3,1,4,5],[2,3,1,5,4],[3,2,4,1,5]...]
```

Thaks for your help I hope I was able to express myself correctly.

Comment: Here's a tip: what you want is a subset of all permutations of the combined list `a + b`, where the order of the elements in the original `a` is maintained.

Comment: Excuse me, I don't understand. You said without changing the order of "a". Then "ans" shows all elements mixed up. It's what do you want to avoid? When you say without changing the order of a, you mean "a" in first position always or "a" fixed and the other list changing? Could you show us your expected output?

Comment: ans is the expected output, I mean the position of elements of a should be fixed as you can see in ans 3,1,5 is always present in the same order.

Comment: @moonify Do you require the order of the inserted elements of `b` to be maintained as well?

Comment: @JethroCao No, only the elements of a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most clean way of doing this, but here's what I mean:

```py
from itertools import permutations

a = [3,1,5]
b = [2,4]

def a_order_is_same(perm):
    i3, i1, i5 = perm.index(3), perm.index(1), perm.index(5)
    return i3 < i1 < i5

ans = [p for p in permutations(a+b) if a_order_is_same(p)]

for p in ans:
    print(p)

--------------------------------------------------

(3, 1, 5, 2, 4)
(3, 1, 5, 4, 2)
(3, 1, 2, 5, 4)
(3, 1, 2, 4, 5)
(3, 1, 4, 5, 2)
(3, 1, 4, 2, 5)
(3, 2, 1, 5, 4)
(3, 2, 1, 4, 5)
(3, 2, 4, 1, 5)
(3, 4, 1, 5, 2)
(3, 4, 1, 2, 5)
(3, 4, 2, 1, 5)
(2, 3, 1, 5, 4)
(2, 3, 1, 4, 5)
(2, 3, 4, 1, 5)
(2, 4, 3, 1, 5)
(4, 3, 1, 5, 2)
(4, 3, 1, 2, 5)
(4, 3, 2, 1, 5)
(4, 2, 3, 1, 5)
```

Comment: If your `a` is a more general list, possibly with more elements, than of course you cannot hardcore the indices of the elements to be compared. In that case, the `a_order_is_same` function would need to be a 2-arg function and take `a` as an argument as well.

Comment: Yes it worked! Thanks. Now I am trying to define the general function so it can work for a generic list.

Comment: @moonify Great, and yes that's the key function which filters out invalid permutations. Let me know if you'd like help with that one.

Comment: I'm trying to append the indexes to a list inside the function, but I have no clue how I should return the function.

Comment: Have a look at the `all()` and/or `any()` built-in functions. Basically if `all` elements of `a` that are also inside `perm` maintain `a`'s order, you'd return `true`; or if `any` pair of elements of `a` inside `perm` do not maintain the order, return `false`.

Comment: Here's a way to get the indices of elements of `a` inside of `perm`. `a_elements_indices = [perm.index(i) for i in a]`. And using this, if the computed indices are not monotonically increasing, then you know that particular `perm` list cannot be a valid candidate in your final answer.

Answer (score 0):

I give you another option.

```
import itertools 
                        
a = [3,1,5]
b = [2,4]
            
c = [b +[a]][0] #0 to get only one level of nested

perm = [x for x in itertools.permutations(c, 3)] 
            
ans = []
```

Here is the formula to get your "ans" output:

```
for i in range(len(perm)): 
            
    groups = perm[i] #this is the subset like [2, 4, [3, 1, 5]]

    #flatten the list or returns integer
    clean = [y for x in groups for y in (x if isinstance(x,list) else [x])]

    ans.append(clean)

    print(clean)
```

[[2, 4, 3, 1, 5], [2, 3, 1, 5, 4], [4, 2, 3, 1, 5], [4, 3, 1, 5, 2], [3, 1, 5, 2, 4], [3, 1, 5, 4, 2]]